# 128-bit PHP Encryption & Decryption of Data

Tags: php, encryption

I have a client who requires all of the data stored in the MySQL database to be encrypted with 128-bit encryption.

Assuming that before all data is inserted into the DB, a PHP function is run to encrypt it. Then, when I pull the data from the database, I run a decryption function to spit out the original text/info.

Can someone point in me in the right direction. I understand that the functions will use a shared/common key to encrypt and decrypt, but what makes it 128bit? Are there prebuilt functions in PHP that do this?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, "128-bit encryption" refers to [symmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) using a 128-bit key.  [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-128 is an excellent choice for an encryption algorithm.

You will also need to choose a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation): CBC, CFB, OFB and CTR are all good choices if you only need privacy, but if you also want to protect the data against tampering, you should use an [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode such as [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode).  Do *not* use ECB mode unless all your records are shorter than a single AES block (also 128 bits), and preferably not even if they are.

Depending on the mode you've chosen, you will typically also need to generate an initialization vector (IV) for each record, which should be a unique and unpredictable random cipher block (128 bits for AES).  There are many ways to generate one, but two good ones ([recommended by NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf)) are either using the output of a [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG) or encrypting a unique ID in ECB mode (this is one of the rare cases for which it is OK to use).  Depending on the crypto library you're using, it may take care of this for you.  Please do note that, if you ever change the encrypted data in a record, you should always change the IV too.

As the other answers note, [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) is a good choice for a crypto library if you're using PHP.

Comment: Many thanks for the info. I am wondering if you could show me an example of a complete encrypt and decrypt function? For eg, if my String is "This is a string" and it is stored as $string?

Answer (score 1):

I hope [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) is your solution. Refer two functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` on the page and grab the idea.

Answer (score 1):

yes.You need to study about the classes/API using for encryption in which they must mentioned that.They are also dependent on algoritham that which type of algorithm you are using.Please [follow this link to learn more about this](http://www.coderelic.com/examples/AES_Encryption_Example.php).[Here is a](http://www.ssa.gov/encryption.htm) breif explaination about encryption.You can found a [sample of code here](http://www.coderelic.com/examples/AES_Encryption_Example.php) but [mycrypt](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php) is more recommended